# Facebook Webhook - Testing an Ad click

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I couldn't find this answered anywhere else so I apologize if it's common knowledge and I've just missed it, but my question is simple: how do you test a click on a Facebook ad to make sure your webhook is setup properly and working? Using the "View on Mobile" method only allows you to test once (at least that's all I've been able to do since I am no longer a unique lead).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to test and feel like an idiot. Test tool here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lead-ads-testing